Realizar resta entre dos columnas data frame en R y acumular el conteo por cada columna con condición
Tengo el siguiente dataframe en r:



variable
A
B
C
D




Primera
2
2
3
4


Segunda
3
2
2
2


Tercera
4
5
5
3


Cuarta
5
2
1
1



Quisiera ir restando B-A, C-B, D-C...  y luego contar si =0 ,  >0,  <0
No necesito la resta individual pero la escribo para el ejemplo:



variable
B
C
D




Primera
0
1
1


Segunda
-1
0
0


Tercera
1
0
-2


Cuarta
3
-1
0



ahora crear las listas contando por cada columna si es mayor, menor o igual a  "0" columna:

suben = 2, 1, 1
bajan = 1, 1, 1
mantiene = 1, 2, 2


Hola Rodrigo, te recomiendo realizar [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Utiliza la herramienta de [edit] para agregar el código lo que has intentado y explica dónde falla o no sabes como continuar.

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, imaginando unos datos como los de tu ejemplo
data <- read.table(text="variable   A   B   C   D
Primera 2   2   3   4
Segunda 3   2   2   2
Tercera 4   5   5   3
Cuarta  5   2   1   1", header=TRUE)

Para restar, puedes hacerlo por columna, usando with evitas anteponer el nombre de data.frame y el código es más compacto, una vez que tienes las restas simplemente sumas por columna las tres condiciones :
restas <- with(data, cbind(B=B-A, C=C-B, D=D-C))

colSums(restas > 0)   # Suma
colSums(restas < 0)   # Resta 
colSums(restas == 0)  # Mantiene

Si quieres algo un poco más genérico en cuando a las restas:
restas <- list()
for (i in 2:(ncol(data)-1)) {
  restas[[i-1]] <- cbind(data[, i+1] - data[, i])
}
restas <- setNames(restas, colnames(data)[3:ncol(data)])
data.frame(restas)

